# How to achieve api proxying in production in vue 2?

Tags: cors, vue.js, vuejs2

There is [section3](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) in vuejs-templates docs which explains how to proxy api request in development mode. How to make similar for production. I mean when you run production version of app how to achieve a substitution of /api to 'http://domain.dev'.

On server side, the CORS is disable
So it looks that I am supposed to proxy request no matter development or production mode.
It works fine using proxyTable in dev but not working production version of app due to CORS restriction.

Any Help would highly be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> On server side, the CORS is disable So it looks that I am supposed to proxy request no matter development or production mode

No. In production, there is no need to run the development server (you shoulnd't, under any circumstances!) Therefore, there's no need for proxying.

You just run your production backend server and serve the built assets from the `/dist` folder.

Comment: Yes, I tried to /dist folder but still getting the CORS error.  XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://domain.dev/v1/intervals'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mag.prod' is therefore not allowed access. showing this error

Comment: are you serving the assets from domain.dev? are domain, protocol (http / https) and port the same for the API server and the one serving the app?

Comment: No, I am serving the assets from mag.prod and both are served from HTTP only

Comment: Then what part of your code is connecting to `domain.dev/v1/internals` ? In your production build, all URLs should point to their production counterparts, there should be no development URLs left.

Comment: what if you add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mag.prod` to your API response